# Rails association with "root" params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

What will be best way to found "root" params of called method in rails?

```
User.first.comments # => [#<Comment id: "1", name: "First comment" ...
```

and I need something like this:

```
User.first.comments #<User id:1, name:"First User", comments: [
  #<Comment id: "1", name: "First comment" ..., #<Comment ... ]
```

needed for serialization..
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, this problem actually probably has nothing to do with `includes`. Whether the user's comments are retrieved with an N + 1 query or not is irrelevant.

I think what you probably need is something like [RABL](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails). I've used it and it's awesome.

Comment: Im now using this https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers, but problem is when I have more then one param to fetch (like comment and his rating) so need to fetch comment and check rating, chose comments what correspond and send to json.

Comment: I've used `active_model_serializers` a tiny bit and I found RABL to be easier to use. You might want to give it a spin. It may be clear, with RABL, how to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

`User.first.includes(:comments)`?

Comment: I try before but I still getting undefined method 'includes'

Comment: That's because my answer is wrong. Who's upvoting this crap?!

Answer (score 2):

It's the other way round:

```
user = User.includes(:comments).first
# SQL queries
# => #<User ...>
```

Now you can access the comments without another database access:

```
user.comments
# => [#<Comment ...>, #<Comment ...>]
```

Comment: This work, but no assoc included, I must call User.includes(:comments).first.comments to get assoc...

Comment: That's right, but the comments are fetched along with the user, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, thats good, is there anyway hot to merge together? to get #<User comments: "and here array with user comments?">, merge (method) wont work for me..